# List of prime powers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

I have a list of not necessarily distinct prime powers.  For example: {2,3,4,25,2,3}.  I want to combine (multiply) the highest prime powers for each prime.  In this case 25*3*4 = 300 since 25 is the highest power of prime 5, 3 is the highest power of prime 3, and 4 is the highest power of prime 2.  Now I want to delete these three elements from the list and repeat the process until the list is empty.  In this case I want the list {300,6,2}.  I would be happy to have a simple (easy to understand) code even at the expense of efficiency.  The prime powers in my original list (input) can be limited to say the first 200 primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty,

```
fun[lst_] := 
 Module[{int, num, res}, 
  int = Sort /@ GatherBy[Join @@ (FactorInteger /@ lst), First];
  num = Times @@ Power @@@ (Last@# & /@ int);
  res = Flatten[Map[Power @@ # &, Most /@ int, {2}]];
  {num, res}
  ]
rec[lt_] := 
 First@NestWhile[{Append[#[[1]], fun[#[[2]]][[1]]], 
     fun[#[[2]]][[2]]} &, {{}, lt}, Length[#[[2]]] > 0 &]
```

so,
`rec[list]` yields {300,6,2} and

`rec[{2,2,2,3}]` yields {6,2,2}.

Comment: I would like to use your code as part of a code that will return the decomposition of the modulo multiplication group of integer n into a direct product of cyclic groups.  I want to submit the sequence to Sloane's OEIS.  If you would like,  I will list you as co-author of the sequence...  or ... give proper accreditation for the code  ... or neither.  Please advise, and thank you very much.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer sent you an email

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer  I was always curious about the criteria for publishing code snippets on OEIS ...

Comment: @belisarius I referred Geoffrey to your updated code...he seems happy with a lot of the answers...

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks. My curiosity comes from years of checking OEIS snippets only to find them almost always inappropriate for my needs. I never understood how they select the coding style (performance? clarity? code length?). This of course isn't related to your answer up there!

Comment: @belisarius.  In my experience the "criteria" for a code to be published in OEIS is only that it CORRECTLY returns a reasonable number of terms in a reasonable amount of time.  Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
mmg[l_List] := Module[{gb},
  gb = GatherBy[First /@ FactorInteger@Sort[l, Greater], First];
  Times @@@ (Power @@@ # & /@ Flatten[gb, {{2}, {1}}])
  ]

mmg[{2, 3, 4, 25, 2, 3}]
(* {300, 6, 2} *)

mmg[{2, 2, 2, 3}]
(* {6, 2, 2} *)
```

Comment: If my list is {2,2,2,3} I want the code to return {6,2,2}.  The code you are giving returns {6,2}.

Comment: By the way, If you are interested in number theory, what I want will be the group structure of the modulo multiplication group of an integer n.  For example if n=72 then the group is isomorphic to C_2 X C_2 X C_6.  Also thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer I think I fixed it. Please recheck

Answer (score 2):

This is the first step to get the 300, note that rad function is https://oeis.org/A007947

```
rad[n_]:=Times@@(First@#&/@FactorInteger@n)
(* rad is Largest squarefree number dividing n *)
mylist = {2, 3, 4, 25, 2, 3}
```

*STEP-1: Sort the list*

```
mylist = Sort[mylist]
```

*STEP-2: Split the list in to distinct power of primes*

```
mylist = Split[mylist, rad[#1]==rad[#2]&]
```

*STEP-3: Take the last 3 elements*

```
mylist = Map[Last, Take[mylist, -3]]
```

*STEP-4: Multiply them*

```
Times@@mylist
```

Comment: More compactly: `rad[n_Integer?Positive] := Times @@ FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]`. You can use `SplitBy[]` instead in step 2.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't how to make the process repeat.  For example, how do I remove the elements { 3,4,25} from the original list {2,3,4,25,2,3}.    I want to repeat this process with {2,2,3}.  Also is step 1 necessary since we are going to split the list in step 2?